# Round 3.666666 to 3.66 in python

Tags: python

I tired to round 3.666666 for two digit and get 3.66. But Round() function give me 3.67. 
Is there a way to solve this problem with the round function without converting it to string type?

a=round(3.666666,2)

Comment: 3.666666 rounded to two digits is 3.67 (not 3.66). It would be easier to convert to string and back for this non-standard rounding.

Comment: @TammoHeeren There are different types of rounding: Round to the nearest, round up, and round down. It is in no way _non-standard_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using

```
import math
x = math.floor(x * 100) / 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `math.floor()` instead of round. `floor` rounds down, `ceil` rounds up, `round` rounds mathematically, either up or down.

To round to two characters after the decimal point, you can multiply it with 10^2 (100) before rounding and then divide it afterwards by the same number.

Here is an example:

```
import math
math.floor(value * 100) / 100
```